# Analysis all games by a chess.com user?

Tags: analysis, chess.com

How do I analyze the moves made by a user by looking at all the games played by a Chess.com player? What I'm exactly looking for is how I do make openings as black. Aggregates results would be amazing.

Comment: So are you just looking for the history of what openings you played as Black and whether the games ended up as win/loss/draw? Or is there more to it?

Answer (score 3):

https://www.openingtree.com/

This is a very good website that has been featured by IM Eric Rosen, and many others. It is easy to use and is fully customizable. All you put in is a username, website and color and you are good to go!